# handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os 
import datetime


#ヘッドレス実行　※全画面用
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

driver.get("https://パズドラ.gamewith.jp/")
#driver.get("https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-using-python/")
#driver.get("https://pad.gungho.jp/member/")
#driver.get("https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/dl/oogaki-zip.html")

#保存する画像ファイル名
fname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

#スクショ保存ディレクトリが存在しなければ生成
if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+"\\ss") == False:
    os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"\\ss")

#ウインドウサイズをWebサイトに合わせて変更　※全画面用
width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollWidth;")
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
driver.set_window_size(width,height)

#スクショをPNG形式で保存
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.getcwd() + "\\ss\\" + fname + ".png")
```

error

```
t[0901/133518.496:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/133522.374:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/133527.577:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/133527.862:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

I am writing source code to take screenshots of an entire website with selenium, but some sites give me a handshake failed error message and others do not. Most of the time, when I get the handshake failed error message, I can't get a screenshot. How can I get rid of this error message? Please help.